# Oracle does not use function-based index for regex_replace with bind variables

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, oracle11g

I have a table in my Oracle 11g database with non formatted text in a column, which shall be displayed as it was entered. Anyway, a user shall be able to search for that text in any possible format (regarding punctuation). I fulfil that requirement by introducing a function-based index on the column:

```
CREATE INDEX "MY_REGEX_INDEX" ON "MY_TABLE" (UPPER( REGEXP_REPLACE ("MY_COLUMN",'[:punct:]','')))
```

When I query this index with

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE UPPER(REGEXP_REPLACE(,'[:punct:]', ''))='123'
```

it works fine. The execution plan contains a proper usage of my new (and highly selective) index.

But when I use bind variables for the regex pattern, it does not work anymore.

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE UPPER(REGEXP_REPLACE(,:pattern, ''))='123'
```

The pattern variable contains the pattern which is constant, but anyway, the optimizer refuses any usage of the index. Somehow, Oracle's bind peeking does not kick in.

Unfortunately, I have no possibility to not use literals instead of bind variables, because my application uses Hibernate in order to generate the SQL. Hints didn't work out neither.

I am no Oracle expert - is there any way to make Oracle "understand" my bind variables and use the index? Didn't find anything related to my topic in the docs, except the fact that I actually can use bind variables for the pattern.

Any is help highly appreciated.

Comment: That's odd that the hint did not work.  Can you pleases show the code and index definitions and the explain plans?

Comment: I don't understand why you're using a bind variable for a constant, but I don't use Hibernate so maybe this is normal behaviour? I'm not entirely surprised it doesn't use the index by default, as you're using a different function call (even if it looks the same once the bind is substituted); but I also would have thought a hint would work. How did you apply the hint?

Comment: @sorencito: If you use a bind variable for the pattern, Oracle cannot use your index since the query plan needs to be independent of the bind variable values and your index only works for a single pattern. It don't buy your argument that you cannot use literals because of Hibernate. If that's the problem, then create a new question "How to use REGEXP_REPLACE with a fixed pattern in Hibernate".

Comment: @Alex Poole I applied the hint hint after the select clause. Regular syntax, but a bit complicated. I'll update my question tomorrow. The hint looks like the most promising alternative.

Comment: @Codo: Actually there is a way to hack Hibernate. The solution is ugly and costly. I'll post it as an alternative answer if it turns out that Oracle cannot do what I think it should be able to do as of version 11g with bind peeking and cursor sharing. Oracle can indeed have several plans for a bind variable and it looks into them before establishing a plan.

Comment: I can't see why a hack is needed in Hibernate. This should be straight-forward. But without seeing the code, it's difficult to discuss.

Comment: @Codo Let's give Hibernate another try. I'll post the code plus the idea of the hack tomorrow. The hack would involve a hard coded regex pattern in a new custom function of a custom dialect. Show me it's easier than that :-)

Comment: You still haven't said what the problem is with Hibernate, so I'm wondering if it's interpreting the fixed `:punct` as a bind variable, maybe? If so can you just construct it as partial string, like `'[[:'||'punct:]]'`?

Comment: @Alex Poole: No, it did not interpret the string as a bind variable due to the :punct. It just always passes strings as bind variables and can't be convinced to do anything else.

Comment: @Codo: I just posted my Hibernate workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it doesn't answer why the bind variable stops the index being used, or why a hint is ignored (which I've verified, but Oracle is free to ignore a hint I suppose - hence the name), you could take another approach and use a virtual column instead:

```
drop index my_regex_index;

alter table my_table add my_regexp_column generated always
  as (upper(regexp_replace(my_column, '[[:punct:]]')));

create index my_regex_index on my_table (my_regexp_column);
```

Then a query will use that index, as there is no bind to worry about, and no extra (constant) value to pass around:

```
select * from my_table where my_regexp_column = '123';

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                |     1 |   204 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| MY_TABLE       |     1 |   204 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | MY_REGEX_INDEX |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Of course, this assumes you can add the columns, and that Hibernate will handle it properly. I don't see why not, but I don't use it...

Comment: The best way would probably be just another column that I fill from the application layer. That way I do not duplicate the regex logic inside the application and the database. Anyway, this solution is very close and solves the issue just as well.

Comment: @sorencito - this approach saves you having to fill it from the application layer though, the DB does that automatically, so you reduce the data sent to the DB. And it means the application doesn't have to do the regex on query, it just has to know the name of the virtual column. Maybe I'm missing something though *8-)

Comment: Got your point. I just have to change the application in order to retrieve the new column :-)

Answer (score 0):

See the section on [the query optimizer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/optimops.htm#PFGRF10101) in the Performance and Tuning Guide. In the table of Optimizer Operations it says:

1. Evaluation of expressions and conditions -
   The optimizer first evaluates expressions and conditions **containing constants** as fully as possible.
2. Statement transformation -
   For complex statements involving, for example, correlated subqueries or views, the optimizer might transform the original statement into an equivalent join statement.
3. Choice of optimizer goals -
   The optimizer determines the goal of optimization. See "Choosing an Optimizer Goal".
4. Choice of access paths -
   For each table accessed by the statement, the optimizer chooses one or more of the available access paths to obtain table data. See "Understanding Access Paths for the Query Optimizer".
5. Choice of join orders -
   For a join statement that joins more than two tables, the optimizer chooses which pair of tables is joined first, and then which table is joined to the result, and so on. See "How the Query Optimizer Chooses Execution Plans for Joins".`

(emphasis mine)

My take on this is that by including the regular expression as a bind variable it's not possible for it to take the contents of the bind variable into account when determining what to do.

Best of luck.

Comment: Oracle 11g can do that. The mechanism is called bind peeking.

Comment: *Bind peeking* tends to be a performance problem of Oracle before 11g rather than a magic feature of 11g.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I ended up changing Hibernates Oracle dialect. Depending on Oracle using my hint was a bit too vague and would have required a client change as well. Alex Poole's answer was good, but would involve database evolution AND a client change. So here goes my solution:

I subclassed Hibernates Oracle10gDialect (an 11g version isn't present in my version of Hibernate).

I registered a new function in it:

```
@Override
protected void registerFunctions() {
    super.registerFunctions();
    registerFunction("punctuation_replace", new PunctuationReplacerSQLFunction() );
}
```

I wrote the PunctuationReplacerSQLFunction:

```
public class PunctuationReplacerSQLFunction implements SQLFunction {

   [...]

    @Override
    public String render(Type firstArgumentType, List arguments, SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory) {   
        return "REGEX_REPLACE" + "(" + arguments.iterator().next() + ", '[:punct:]', '')";
    }
}
```

And then use it like this in my code:

```
jpaCriteriaBuilder.function("punctuation_replace", String.class, path);
```

The hacky thing about it is that I hardwire the pattern as a String, so that for any new pattern or replacement string I'd have to provide a new function. Anyway, it works. My SQL - for some other test szenario not related to my example in the question - looks like this:

```
SELECT demoentity0_.ID           AS ID2_15_,
       demoentity0_.VERSION      AS VERSION3_15_,
       demoentity0_.NAME         AS NAME11_15_,
FROM DEMO_ENTITY demoentity0_
WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(demoentity0_.NAME, '[:punct:]', '')=?
```

Comment: If you had opened a new question, one could have answered with code. The problematic use of REGEXP_REPLACE is more related to the use of JPA criterias. It wouldn't be a problem with HQL or Hibernate's native criteria building (see Restrictions.sqlRestriction). What did your original solution look like when Oracle wouldn't use the index?

Comment: @Codo The solution was similar. We used jpaCriteriaBuilder.function ("regexp_replace", ...). Nothing speaks against answering in code. Anyway, using Hibernate directly is not an option for the project I am working on.